# need to add all post ids to query_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I need to get all post ids related to specific category in the query_posts().

I am currently using the following code:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=11&p=-1');
while ((have_posts()) : the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

I was hoping that inserting -1 in 'p=' will bring all posts but it doesn't. 
anyone can help?

Thanks in advance,
Eyal

Comment: need more code , and are the ids in same table or different tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just hope Your actual code does not contain this unbalanced parenthesis 
@while ((have_posts())) : the_post();

As per: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=7' );

this means we need to display post which has id=7.

Now as per your code:
query_posts('cat=11&p=-1');

this means, display those posts which are in category id =7 and have id=-1, which doesn't look very useful to me.

In My case:
query_posts('cat=11'), as well as 
query_posts('cat=11&posts_per_page=-1')
 are working smoothly.

Now would you like to tell how this plugin of yours is depended on "p", so we can find an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Wordpress Functin Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts): To Retrieve

> All Posts in a Category. The "Blog pages show at most" parameter in
>   Settings > Reading can influence your results. To overcome this, add
>   the 'posts_per_page' parameter. For example:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

> This will returns ALL posts from the category.

Comment: not working :-( I must have the 'p' in the query because there is a plugin that uses it.

Comment: @EyalBinehaker Then try `query_posts('cat=11&posts_per_page=-1');`